# Python class static method that requires another static method

Tags: python

Is it ok to have multiple staticmethods that calls from each other.

something like:

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.var = self.static1(a)

    @staticmethod
    def static1(i):
        i += 1
        return self.static2(i)

    @staticmethod
    def static2(i):
        return i * 3

c = Myclass(1)
```

I got :

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: If you need `self`, your method is not `static` by definition…

Answer (score 2):

No need to prepend with '`self.`'. Just call `MyClass.static2(i)`

Comment: Of course, if you hardcode `MyClass`, you won't get the effects of inheritance, which may be significant…

Answer (score 2):

use the `@classmethod` decorator
function will denote it does not change anything in the instance while you can access the class via first parameter `cls`

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.var = self.static1(a)

    @classmethod
    def static1(cls,i):
        i += 1
        return cls.static2(i)

    @staticmethod
    def static2(i):
        return i * 3
```